# Read .h5 file in matlab without knowing dataset name

Tags: matlab, hdfs

I have a .h5 file which I can read in python as pandas.read_pickle('X.h5','r'). Now I want to load this in MATLAB-2014a and I don't know dataset name.
I tried to get info but got error

```
info=h5info('X.h5');

Error using h5infoc
The HDF5 library encountered an error and produced the following stack trace 
information:

H5F_locate_signature    unable to find a valid file signature
H5F_super_read          unable to find file signature
H5F_open                unable to read superblock
H5Fopen                 unable to open file
```

---

Can someone help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

> To get a quick view into the contents of an HDF5 file, use the h5disp function.

```
h5disp('X.h5')
```

You can find more about the data set using this function.
See more from [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-hierarchical-data-format-hdf5-files.html).

Comment: It didn't worked either. I get the same error as mentioned in question